# Mutex usage in ACE Event handler/TimerHandler/Event priority

Tags: frameworks, mutex, ace

I have a question regarding synchronization using mutex in ACE framework.
Task  A has been registered with a Timer Handler. In Task A function foo is called. A Critical Section in foo is protected using recursive mutexes. The variables that are used by foo function ,are used (write/read) acces by handle_timeout. That means that we need to protect them.

We have the following piece of pseudocode

```
foo()
lock(recursive_mutex)
C.S
unlock(recursive_mutex)

handle_timeout()
{
lock(recursive_mutex)
C.S
unlock(recursive_mutex)
}
```

If the handle_timeout takes place before foo release the lock, will a deadlock take place?

If we have a Task B with a highest priority that is registered with an other event. If this event fired when the handle_timoeout ,what will happen?
Will we have a context switch and the second evcent start processing?

Comment: Is any answer  to this issue?